# Why can't I subclass 'OCKSurveyTaskViewController' from CareKit?

Tags: swift, xcode, carekit

***Note: I tried posting on the apple developer forums 2 days ago and didn't receive any responses as well***

I've been literally stuck on this portion of my project because I want to mirror the way apple has their care view setup for displaying tasks to users. I for some reason, can't subclass the 'OCKSurveyTaskViewController' as the error I'm getting is:

"Cannot find type 'OCKSurveyTaskViewController' in scope"

I've reinstalled CareKit through SPM 2 or three times and I can't figure out why I can't subclass it even when I see the exact OCKSurveyTaskViewController.swift file and it listed in the code as an open class in the CareKit/iOS/Task/ViewController directory from Xcode.

Could anyone please give me some guidance or perhaps another way to display the ORKTasks I have established for users on a daily basis in another fashion? I prefer the method apple Is using in their wwdc21 CareKit code along but alas I've been stuck on this for too long and this is needed to get to my next step.

Here's my files code:

```
import UIKit
import CareKit
import CareKitUI
import CareKitStore
import ResearchKit
import os.log

class StudyTaskFeedViewController: OCKDailyTasksPageViewController, OCKSurveyTaskViewController {}
```

Here's the code to the OCKSurveyTaskViewController.swift file:

```
#if !os(watchOS) && canImport(ResearchKit)

import CareKitStore
import CareKitUI
import ResearchKit
import UIKit

// MARK: OCKSurveyTaskViewControllerDelegate

public protocol OCKSurveyTaskViewControllerDelegate: AnyObject {

    func surveyTask(
        viewController: OCKSurveyTaskViewController,
        for task: OCKAnyTask,
        didFinish result: Result<ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, Error>)

    func surveyTask(
        viewController: OCKSurveyTaskViewController,
        shouldAllowDeletingOutcomeForEvent event: OCKAnyEvent) -> Bool
}

public extension OCKSurveyTaskViewControllerDelegate {

    func surveyTask(
        viewController: OCKSurveyTaskViewController,
        for task: OCKAnyTask,
        didFinish result: Result<ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason, Error>) {
        // No-op
    }

    func surveyTask(
        viewController: OCKSurveyTaskViewController,
        shouldAllowDeletingOutcomeForEvent event: OCKAnyEvent) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}

open class OCKSurveyTaskViewController: OCKTaskViewController<OCKTaskController, OCKSurveyTaskViewSynchronizer>, ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate {

    private let extractOutcome: (ORKTaskResult) -> [OCKOutcomeValue]?

    public let survey: ORKTask

    public weak var surveyDelegate: OCKSurveyTaskViewControllerDelegate?

    public convenience init(
        task: OCKAnyTask,
        eventQuery: OCKEventQuery,
        storeManager: OCKSynchronizedStoreManager,
        survey: ORKTask,
        viewSynchronizer: OCKSurveyTaskViewSynchronizer = OCKSurveyTaskViewSynchronizer(),
        extractOutcome: @escaping (ORKTaskResult) -> [OCKOutcomeValue]?) {

        self.init(
            taskID: task.id,
            eventQuery: eventQuery,
            storeManager: storeManager,
            survey: survey,
            viewSynchronizer: viewSynchronizer,
            extractOutcome: extractOutcome
        )
    }

    public init(
        taskID: String,
        eventQuery: OCKEventQuery,
        storeManager: OCKSynchronizedStoreManager,
        survey: ORKTask,
        viewSynchronizer: OCKSurveyTaskViewSynchronizer = OCKSurveyTaskViewSynchronizer(),
        extractOutcome: @escaping (ORKTaskResult) -> [OCKOutcomeValue]?) {

        self.survey = survey
        self.extractOutcome = extractOutcome

        super.init(
            viewSynchronizer: viewSynchronizer,
            taskID: taskID,
            eventQuery: eventQuery,
            storeManager: storeManager
        )
    }

    override open func taskView(
        _ taskView: UIView & OCKTaskDisplayable,
        didCompleteEvent isComplete: Bool,
        at indexPath: IndexPath,
        sender: Any?) {

        guard isComplete else {

            if let event = controller.eventFor(indexPath: indexPath),

               let delegate = surveyDelegate,

               delegate.surveyTask(
                    viewController: self,
                    shouldAllowDeletingOutcomeForEvent: event) == false {

                return
            }

            let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "Cancel",
                style: .cancel,
                handler: nil
            )

            let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(
                title: "Delete", style: .destructive) { _ in
                
                super.taskView(
                    taskView,
                    didCompleteEvent: isComplete,
                    at: indexPath,
                    sender: sender
                )
            }

            let warningAlert = UIAlertController(
                title: "Delete",
                message: "Are you sure you want to delete your response?",
                preferredStyle: .actionSheet
            )

            warningAlert.addAction(cancelAction)
            warningAlert.addAction(confirmAction)
            present(warningAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            return
        }

        let surveyViewController = ORKTaskViewController(
            task: survey,
            taskRun: nil
        )

        let directory = FileManager.default.urls(
            for: .documentDirectory,
            in: .userDomainMask
        ).last!.appendingPathComponent("ResearchKit", isDirectory: true)

        surveyViewController.outputDirectory = directory
        surveyViewController.delegate = self

        present(surveyViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK: ORKTaskViewControllerDelegate
    
    open func taskViewController(
        _ taskViewController: ORKTaskViewController,
        didFinishWith reason: ORKTaskViewControllerFinishReason,
        error: Error?) {

        taskViewController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        guard let task = controller.taskEvents.first?.first?.task else {
            assertionFailure("Task controller is missing its task")
            return
        }

        if let error = error {
            surveyDelegate?.surveyTask(
                viewController: self,
                for: task,
                didFinish: .failure(error)
            )
            return
        }

        guard reason == .completed else {
            return
        }

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

        guard let event = controller.eventFor(indexPath: indexPath) else {
            return
        }

        guard let values = extractOutcome(taskViewController.result) else {
            return
        }

        let outcome = OCKOutcome(
            taskUUID: event.task.uuid,
            taskOccurrenceIndex: event.scheduleEvent.occurrence,
            values: values
        )

        controller.storeManager.store.addAnyOutcome(
            outcome,
            callbackQueue: .main) { result in

            if case let .failure(error) = result {

                self.surveyDelegate?.surveyTask(
                    viewController: self,
                    for: task,
                    didFinish: .failure(error)
                )
            }

            self.surveyDelegate?.surveyTask(
                viewController: self,
                for: task,
                didFinish: .success(reason)
            )
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: In your class StudyTaskFeedViewController, you are actually trying to do multiple inheritance (from class OCKDailyTasksPageViewController and OCKSurveyTaskViewController). Thats not possible in Swift. If you have seen similar syntax in other Swift code, this is because a class can conform to multiple protocols (in addition to optionally inherit from a superclass).

Comment: Ah I see, definitely understand that multiple inheritance doesn't work with classes. I see now I was trying to inherit the Delegate for OCKSurveyTaskViewController, but still when typing into Xcode, none of the code in the above file was listed in the code completion. For more context, this is how the file should look as I was trying to follow a code along session from WWDC21: https://github.com/carekit-apple/WWDC21-RecoverApp/blob/main/Recover%20Final/Recover/CareFeedViewController.swift

Comment: Depending on your target and environment, you might not even get past the #if statement on the first line. If this does happen, then basically your whole second file won't get compiled.

Comment: Understood! So can I assume that this #if statement is saying "If the target is not WatchOS and can also import ResearchKit framework, then all the objects in this file can be access/used for inheritance"? Also, thank you for taking the time to answer my questions; I've been learning how to code for a few months on my own and now came across the need to use a framework for a project my lab has me leading.

Comment: You are correctly interpreting the condition of the #if compiler directive. However, it is telling the compiler which part of the code it should include in the compilation process and which to exclude. If you have code you want to compile on multiple platforms which do not all support the same functionality, the compiler won't compile that code and you will get errors. With the compiler directives you can conditionally include / exclude code for different platforms, debugging etc. If in your case the condition is not met, the code will be excluded from compilation completely.

Comment: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Statements.html#grammar_compiler-control-statement

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation and reference. I essentially met all the conditions as my target is iOS and have ResearchKit framework imported through CocoaPods (tried importing the ResearchKit.xcodeproj but still didn't work). Still, I'm unable to access anything within this file. If you happen to have the bandwidth, would you be able to see if you're able to create an Xcode project w/ ResearchKit framework (main branch), carekit through spm (main branch), import the frameworks into a file, and check if you can create a class object with the 'OCKSurveyTaskViewControllerDelegate' protocol?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem when I try to reproduce the demostration code form the "Recover" app in my own app. After I compared my project settings with the "Recover", I noticed that I missed to add the capability of "HealthKit" in my target app's Sign&Capabilities. After I added this capability, it worked.